# How to separate presentation layer for Android from Windows in UWP app?

Tags: c#, android, wcf, xamarin, uwp

I have rather larger enterprise class app in Silverlight. I want to convert it to a Windows 10 UWP app, which will be not too hard and I expect about 80% to be done without much problems.

However I see that a UWP app can target Android and Apple using Xamarin.

Can anyone share a practical guide - how to approach this?

I expect 50% of functionality be present in Xamarin "version" of the app - as there will be not enough screen on tablets and other features might be not available.

Whats the best architecture to reuse as much of the code as possible between Windows app and its mobile mini-me?

**How to organize VS projects and share libraries etc?**

*P.S. the data access in the Windows app will be WCF with EF and Oracle. I can easily mirror the WCF calls into REST service for the mobile app.*

Comment: I would argue that this question falls in _both_ primarily opinion-based and too broad. What were your expectations when you wrote the question? Also that you show very little research in your own question, totally mistaking what UWP is and what Xamarin does, or at least how your question appears. It just strengthens the reason to actually close the question. Now this can be sensitive as it is _your_ question and you have feelings about it, but there is no reason to generalize and insult people like you just did. Seeing you have over 3k points you should know how to ask a SO question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Firstly, i would ask the few questions specifiy in https://www.xamarin.com/forms :

### How important are the platform-specific functionality?

### How important are the custom UI

If you answers to the above are, they are not very important.

Then create a Xamarin.Forms proj, and organize your RestAPI services code in the SharedLibrary Proj.

https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/cross-platform/application_fundamentals/shared_projects/

> Shared Projects (also sometimes called Shared Asset Projects) let you write code that is shared between multiple target projects including Xamarin applications. The code is compiled as part of each referencing project and can include compiler directives to help incorporate platform-specific functionality into the shared code base.

However you might also think that you want to use some small specific code to each platform, you can then look at **custom renderer** in each proj,
proj.ios , proj.droid, proj.UWP.

Then you can write the shared Views using XAML in your shared proj.
Hope I answered your questions.

Comment: just to clarify - I was talking about sharing code on UI side. forget server side completely it all is taken care of.. but thanks for custom renderer idea ill look into it.

Comment: @BoppityBop no problem, the only thing i can think of sharing UI code, is the xaml you write in the share project ... happy coding.

Answer (score 3):

UWP can *not* target Android and iOS. However, if you choose a Xamarin.Forms project template you can target UWP, Android and iOS. This will create a Shared or PCL library where you can have platform agnostic code in.

If you choose Xamarin.Forms, don't expect a 1:1 conversion of your Silverlight XAML as the XAML Xamarin.Forms provides is not exactly the same as what Silverlight, WPF or UWP provides natively. It is very similar though, and if your Silverlight application mostly uses standard controls such as buttons, text boxes etc. It won't take you much time to convert the UI.

Xamarin.Forms is not a silver bullet though, so you might have to adjust and maybe even write some custom controls for it, to make your application work on all targeted platforms.

As for a good approach to architect your application, this is primarily opinion based. However, a lot of people use the MVVM pattern to enforce some separation of concerns. This fits very well with Xamarin.Forms as well as it has built in bindings, as you would expect from something using XAML to write UI code in.
But implementing Redux, VIPER or other design patterns should be possible too. You will find most examples using MVVM. There are also a lot of MVVM libraries for Xamarin.Forms out there so you can get a head start.

Xamarin.Forms is a great way of sharing UI code accross platforms. However, if you want *full* control of your UI, you could consider writing native apps using Xamarin, although without Forms. This approach will force you to learn about each of the platform in more depth, as they behave differently in terms of lifecycles, UI and more.

The project structure a Xamarin.Forms project gives you of either a Shared Project or PCL and then an Application project for each targeted platform is a nice way to attack this. Shared code goes into PCL or Shared project, platform specific code goes into Application projects. How, exactly you manage and structure your code, is up to *you*.

TL;DR: MVVM, don't expect 1:1 conversion from Silverlight to Xamarin.Forms.

Comment: ok. migration to xamarin as the main codebase does not make sense to me for many reasons.. It simply will not do.. I was hoping to make a UWP and then a spawn a mini-clone with cutdown functionality to target android/ios.. (mostly in anticipation that it wont be difficult).